# return value not shown by Qt Creator debugger

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

My environment:

- Windows 10, 64-bit
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- Qt 5.6.2
- Qt Creator 4.8.1

According to Qt Creator documentation, it should be possible to have Qt Creator's debugger show the value returned by a function when exiting the function. Excerpt from http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html#local-variables-and-function-parameters :

*The Locals view consists of the Locals pane and the Return Value pane (hidden when empty).*

*Whenever a program stops under the control of the debugger, it retrieves information about the topmost stack frame and displays it in the Locals view. The Locals pane shows information about parameters of the function in that frame as well as the local variables. If the last operation in the debugger was returning from a function after pressing Shift+F11, the Return Value pane displays the value returned by the function.*

The problem is, I can't see the return pane (and thus the value returned by the last function).

Here is a minimal example:

After compiling a minimal project, I set a breakpoint in `main()`, when `foo()` is about to be called, and start the debugger (F5). The debugger correctly stops at the breakpoint:

[image]

I give command *Step Into* (F11) to the debugger. In the debugger, I can see that control reaches the called function, `foo()`:

[image]

Now for the critical step. I give command *Step Out* (Shift+F11) to the debugger. As expected, control returns to the caller (`main()`), but the value returned by `foo()` is not shown:

[image]

So, how can I see the return value?

Here is the content of my *Compile Output* pane:

```
15:45:44: Running steps for project debugger_return_pane...
15:45:44: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\experiments\debugger_return_pane\debugger_return_pane.pro -spec win32-msvc2015 "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
15:45:44: The process "C:\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
15:45:44: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" -f C:/experiments/build-debugger_return_pane-Desktop_Qt_5_6_3_MSVC2015_64bit2-Debug/Makefile qmake_all

jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores

15:45:45: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
15:45:45: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\DebuggerReturnPane.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\debugger_return_pane -I. -I..\..\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\include -I..\..\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -I..\..\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -I..\..\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I..\..\Qt\5.6.2\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.8348.0.jom
main.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\DebuggerReturnPane.exe @C:\Users\dave\AppData\Local\Temp\DebuggerReturnPane.exe.8348.78.jom
15:45:45: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
15:45:45: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: The code seems to be optimized by the compiler, would you show us the command line used by `cl -c ...` in the `compilation tab` ?

Comment: I just added the content of my *Compile Output* pane to my original post.

Comment: You can disable the code optimization by adding this in your .pro file : `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += -Od` (with debug configuration, for C++ source file)

Comment: As expected, adding `-Od` to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG` did not help: the behavior is exactly the same as in my original post. (As expected, because `-Od` is the default.)

Answer (score 0):

This has now been acknowledged as a bug in Qt Creator: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-21913

Answer (score -1):

At the top of the file you need to include the QDebug in this way:

```
#include <QDebug>
```

and so before the return you need to print the value returned by the foo function in this way:

```
qDebug() << value;
```

Comment: Printing to the console, as you suggest, can be useful, but is an entire different matter. What I would like to see is the return value of each function, as the code is being debugged. This is possible in most debuggers, and should be possible also in Qt Creator (according to Qt Creator manual), but for some reason does not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me , after the debugger stop to line 8, F10 (Step Over), and as you can see the return value is shown on the right panel[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wVa3.png)

Comment: What you are seeing is `a`, a local variable which happens to be assigned value returned from `foo()`. The debugger has a functionality which should allow you to see the value returned by a function as you exit the function.